# ASP.NET MVC5 controller and Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I implemented a design as [described here](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc), with ASP.NET MVC5, repository pattern, UoW and Autofac.

Everything works for controllers with a single service, but I have a controller that requires three services:

```
public MyController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, IService3 service3)
{
    _service1= service1;
    _service2= service2;
    _service3= service3;
}
```

Now, I register the services like this:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("namespace.service"))
              .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
              .AsImplementedInterfaces()
              .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

At runtime, I get this error:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'namespace.Controllers.MyController' can be Invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Can not resolve parameter
>   '.service.Service1 service1 constructor of 'Void .ctor ...

Comment: Have you registered all your services in Autofac container?

Comment: i update the post, yes, I register all the service. 
individually their work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter how many constructor parameters your controller has. If Autofac reports that it cannot resolve `service1`, it means that `IService1` is not registered.

There might be an issue with registering assembly types due to wrong query or assembly. To verify this, try commenting out the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` and use `RegisterType<Service1>().As<IService1>().InstancePerRequest()` for all three services and see if it helps. Also check if your module `Load` actually gets called.

If registering services explicitly worked, you can try getting back to `RegisterAssemblyTypes` but use service assembly from the service type instead of loading it by name:

```
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (Service1).Assembly)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest();
```